# Is there a convention for python exit codes?

Tags: python, python-2.7, shell, convention

According to the Python documentation:

> The optional argument arg can be an integer giving the exit status (defaulting to zero), or another type of object. If it is an integer, zero is considered “successful termination” and any nonzero value is considered “abnormal termination” by shells and the like. Most systems require it to be in the range 0-127, and produce undefined results otherwise. Some systems have a convention for assigning specific meanings to specific exit codes, but these are generally underdeveloped; Unix programs generally use 2 for command line syntax errors and 1 for all other kind of errors.

So if I wanted to use the rest of the integer range for exit codes, would there be a convention as to what numbers should be used? I've looked on this site and on others but I cannot find anything related to an agreement on the codes beyond 0,1,2. Is there anything in Python philosophy that might dictate the values I should use?

Comment: 0 for success 1 or -1 for failure.

Comment: @CameronBell -- Don't use `-1`, many systems still like numbers between `0` and `127`.

Comment: Okay yea sorry I meant 1.

Comment: I don't think that this is a good _python_ question since the exit code isn't normally used by _python_ unless you're calling one python program from another -- But the general point here remains...  The primary consumer of the exit code will be a shell or something that is interested in process management.  As such, `0` is _always_ used for success.  Other conventions aren't so strong -- Just document the exit codes if you have more than 2 :-) and maybe tag this with `shell` or something to raise it with a more suitable audience.

Comment: Thanks, that makes sense.

Answer (score 2):

I don't think that this is a good *python* question since the exit code isn't normally used by *python* unless you're calling one python program from another -- But the general point here remains...  The primary consumer of the exit code will be a shell or something that is interested in process management.  As such, `0` is *always* used for success.  Other conventions aren't so strong -- Just document the exit codes if you have more than 2 :-) and maybe tag this with `shell` or something to raise it with a more suitable audience.
                    – mgilson